# Mock a HTTP request error using Nock and Request

Tags: node.js, mocking, request

I have a branch in a function that isn't currently being tested. It's an error handler coming from a `request` operation (using the node module of the same name). Here is the particular line:

```
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) return cb(error);
```

Here is the test:

```
  describe("handles errors", function() {
    it("from the request", function (done) {
    var api = nock('http://football-api.com')
                .get('/api/?Action=today&APIKey=' + secrets.APIKey + '&comp_id=1204')
                .reply(500);

    fixture.getFixture(FixtureMock, function (err, fixture) {
      expect(err).to.exist
      done();
    });
  });
```

Spec fails:

```
Uncaught AssertionError: expected null to exist
```

So either sending a `500` status code as a response with no body does not cause an `error` in the request callback, or I'm testing the wrong thing.

Comment: The end of this issue has a potential for returning an error. https://github.com/pgte/nock/issues/164

Answer (score 7):

Use `replyWithError` from doc:

```
nock('http://www.google.com')
   .get('/cat-poems')
   .replyWithError('something awful happened');
```

Comment: Won't this simply provide a generic (and expected) response, even though the error condition might be different? Maybe best to test for the exact error condition instead.

Answer (score 1):

This variant of @PiotrFryga's answer worked for me, as my request `callback(err, resp, body)` was actually checking for the "ETIMEDOUT" error code in `err`:

```
nock('http://www.google.com')
   .get('/cat-poems')
   .replyWithError({code: "ETIMEDOUT"});
```

Answer (score 0):

The only found workaround is to simulate timeout

```
nock('http://service.com').get('/down').delayConnection(500).reply(200)
unirest.get('http://service.com/down').timeout(100).end(function(err) {
  // err = ETIMEDOUT
});
```

[source](https://github.com/pgte/nock/issues/164#issuecomment-56771025)